# Calculating segment length on circle

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics

I'm building a physical machine and I'm trying to figure out a geometrical problem.

The machine is composed by a cylinder, and the wall of this cylinder is composed by many wooden boards, each of them must be spaced of a value X. What should be the number of wood slats needed, and of which width?

I tried to solve the problem calculating the circonference of the circle and working on it like a straight line. Then I've split the line by using the amount of space I would have to keep between the wooden boards, but then I got stuck.

Graphical rappresentation:

[image]

Any clues? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the comments. In fact, the only data I have is the radius of the circle and the space I need to leave between the wooden boards. I don't have the number of woods. Do I need to brute-force it with an algoritm?

ps: I've updated the image, now it should be more clearer.

Comment: There are n boards and n spaces so that $2\pi r = nw + nX$ where w is the width of a board. and r is the circle radius. For a practical problem you probably will not have all possible values of w available so experiment with   n, w and X.

Comment: If $X$ is fixed then number of wooden boards needed depends on the radius of the circle.Please specify it...

Comment: thanks for the reply! I've updated the question with new information

Comment: You need to have "enough" boards so that the resulting structure looks sufficiently like a cylinder, but not so many that the gaps would occupy the entire circumference of the circle. If you are very good at bending boards around their long axis you could bend two boards into nearly "half-pipe" shapes and use just those two boards (with two gaps) to make your cylinder. But it seems you want more boards than that. Perhaps the number of boards in your diagram would be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul comments, $2\pi r = n(x + y)$, or
$$
2r = \frac{x + y}{\pi/n}.
\tag{1}
$$
This equation expresses your wish to have some (sufficiently large) number $n$ of "board-and-space units" filling the circumference of a circle of radius $r$. "Sufficiently large" means "enough boards that you can pretend the circle is a regular $n$-gon." If you want more accuracy (for $n \geq 3$), use $x + y = 2r\sin(\pi/n)$, or
$$
2r = \frac{x + y}{\sin(\pi/n)}.
\tag{2}
$$
instead.

Since only the space width $x$ is known on the right, there is no unique solution to your problem: For each integer $n \geq 3$, equations (1) and (2) each have a unique solution, i.e., a board width $y > 0$ satisfying the circumference constraint.

What you actually do will depend on whether you'd rather have a specific number of board-and-spaces, or a specific width of board (so you can use standard lumber).

- If you fix $n$, then $y$ is uniquely determined, and you'll probably need to cut lumber to width.
- If you want the largest number of slits while making the fewest cuts/wasting the smallest amount of lumber, you can do this: Plug $x$ and $y$ into (1) or (2) (depending on how much accuracy you need), and find the *first* (i.e., smallest) integer value of $n$ making *the right-hand side larger* than the left. This tells you how many boards you need. Now plug the known values of $x$ and $n$ into the corresponding equation, calculate $y$, and cut the boards to that width.

For example, if you want to build a cylinder of radius $24$ inches with $1$ inch gaps using $5$-$\frac{3}{4}$ inch boards, then
$$
\frac{2\pi r}{x + y} = \frac{48\pi}{6.75} \approx 22.34,
$$
so you'll have $n = 23$ units. Using equation (2), the boards must be cut to
$$
y = 2r\sin(\pi/n) - x = 48\sin(\pi/23) - 1 \approx 5.5\text{ inches.}
$$

Keep in mind that this discussion makes implicit assumptions:

- The boards are flat (rather than having arcs of circles as cross-sections), and the "radius" is the distance from the center of the cylinder to the *inside edge* (not the inside center line) of a board.
- The gap width $x$ is much smaller than the circumference $2\pi r$.

Comment: Wow you really spent some time on this, would be a shame not to accept... Thanks alot Sir, I understood most of it already from comments and earlier answers, but this one nailed it.

Answer (score 2):

The limit number of wood slats is that there's an upper bound.

If the spacing is $X$ and the radius is $r$ then of course the spacing and assume there's $n$ wood slats, then the spacing alone would take $nX$ of circumference while the total circumference is $2r\pi$. To make this work we must have $2r\pi \ge nX$  or $n \le 2r\pi/X$.

This is assuming that the spacing and the wood slats are properly curved.

After selecting $n$ we could calculate the width of the slats since the total circumference would be $nX + nY = 2r\pi$ which means that $X+Y = 2r\pi/n$.